# Construct an object with a prototype using Function.apply()

Tags: javascript, inheritance, constructor, prototype, instance

I'm having a bit of a dilemma getting my head around JS' prototypal inheritance. What I'm trying to do is:

1. Define an object called **mod**

   ```
   var mod = function() {
       function sayGoodbye() {
           alert("Goodbye!");
       }

       function saySomethingElse(message) {
           alert(message);
       }

       return {
           sayGoodbye: sayGoodbye,
           saySomethingElse: saySomethingElse
       };
   };
   ```
2. Define a prototype object called **proto**

   ```
   var proto = {
       sayHello: function() {
           alert("Hello!");
       }
   };
   ```
3. Set the prototype of **mod** to **proto**

   ```
   mod.prototype = proto;
   ```
4. Call a function that constructs a new instance of **mod** with the **proto** prototype

   ```
   function construct(constructor, args) {

       function constructorWrapper() {
           return constructor.apply(this, args)
       }

       constructorWrapper.prototype = constructor.prototype;

       return new constructorWrapper();
   }

   var foo = construct(mod, ["Other Message 1"]);
   var bar = construct(mod, ["Other Message 2"]);

   console.dir(foo);
   console.dir(bar);
   ```

The *construct* function creates a new instance of **mod** correctly using the *apply* function but it's prototype is not **proto**. What am I missing that prevents **mod** from being constructed with **proto** as it's prototype?

Here is a [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/andrewcourtice/ovpzj7k7/) with the above code.

Thanks heaps!!

Comment: Your `mod` function is a factory that returns an object. It should not be, it should be a constructor (or method) that initialises properties on `this`.

Comment: I wonder why you don't just use `new mod("Other message 1")`?

Comment: @squint: I guess step 4 was supposed to set up the prototype chain. It even would have, if `constructorWrapper` or `constructor` would not have returned an object.

Comment: @Bergi: Oh, I see. He was just transporting it. EDIT: I missed that he was actually assigning the function. Somehow I saw it as an IIFE. I wish people would use function declarations when able.

Comment: So what's likely confusing you is that you can override the object generated by `new`. As Bergi said, you're returning an object from the constructor, and so the actual constructed object is discarded, and your object is returned instead.

Comment: @squint @Bergi: It works if I remove the return statement from the **constructorWrapper** and if **mod** is defined like `function mod() { this.sayGoodbye = function() { ... }; }` but if I use a revealing pattern for **mod**, as written above, without a return statement in **constructorWrapper** it won't give a new instance of **mod**. Is there any way to have the best of both worlds in this situation?

Comment: Is this what you're after? https://jsfiddle.net/ovpzj7k7/7/ It uses `Object.create` to create a new object from the `constructor.prototype`, and then uses `constructor.apply` to apply the constructor to it. In the constructor, instead of returning an object, I assign the functions to `this`.

Comment: The strange thing seems to be that you give `saySomethingElse()` a parameter and ignore the arguments to the `mod/constructor`. If you move the parameter to `mod`, you'll be able to use the constructor argument. https://jsfiddle.net/ovpzj7k7/8/

Comment: That's great @squint. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason the `.prototype` assignment isn't working for you is because setting the prototype chain like this only works when you use the `new` operator on a constructor function.

You created a factory function that returns a newly created object. Get rid of the `return` in `mod` and use `this` to attach your method and use `new` operator when creating instances of `mod` will make the `.prototype` assignment work.

This might be confusing so I updated your fiddle:
https://jsfiddle.net/6fdo649y/1/

There are several ways to achieve what you are trying to do, but this example explains why you don't see `.prototype` work.

```
//Constructor function using this
function Mod(arg1) {
    this.sayGoodbye = function sayGoodbye() {
        alert("Goodbye!");
    }

    this.saySomethingElse = function saySomethingElse(message) {
        alert(message);
    }

    this.arg1 = arg1;
};

var proto = {
    sayHello: function() {
        alert("Hello!");
    }
};

Mod.prototype = proto;

function construct(constructor, args) {

    function constructorWrapper() {
        constructor.apply(this, args)
    }

    constructorWrapper.prototype = constructor.prototype;

    return new constructorWrapper();
}

var foo = construct(Mod, ["Other Message 1"]);
var bar = construct(Mod, ["Other Message 2"]);

console.dir(foo === bar);
console.dir(foo);
console.dir(bar);
```

*edited: added in passing the args through with apply.*

Comment: Please add the changed code to your answer, not (only) to the fiddle.